# Performance degrade from using QThread and multiple signals-and-slots connections

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I am having trouble trying to figure out where this performance degrade in my codes comes from. My program is quite big so I'll simplify using some examples. Say I have a MainUI class subclassed from QMainWindow, which has two member objects, a Worker (subclassed from QThread) and a DisplayPanel (subclassed from QGLWidget). Then a connection is established between a signal from this Worker object (emitted from its run method) and a slot in the DisplayPanel object. And  I see performance degrade in the run method if I increase the number of connections.

Basically what I am describing is (very simplified):

```
class Worker : public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void updateDisplay();

protected:
    void startWorking() {
        // some setup codes
        this->start();
    }

    void run() {
        while (1) {
             // some processing codes
             emit updateDisplay();
        }
    }
};

class DisplayPanel : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_5_0_Core {

    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void refresh() {
        update();
    }
};

class MainUI : public QMainWindow {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainUI(QWidget *parent = 0) {
        // some Ui setup codes
        worker = new Worker();

        num_panels = 5 // arbitrary number
        panels.resize(num_panels);
        for (auto p : panels) {
             p = new DisplayPanel();
             connect(worker, SIGNAL(updateDisplay()), p, SLOT(refresh()));
        }

    }

    void process() {
        worker->startWorking();
    }

private:
    unsigned num_panels;
    Worker* worker;
    std::vector<DisplayPanel*> panels;
};
```

Imagine MainUI::process() was called from the GUI.

What confuses me is that there is some noticeable performance degrade in the while loop of Worker::run() if I increase MainUI::num_panels. From my understanding, the increased number of signals-and-slots connections should not affect the performance of Worker very much because the queued requests to DisplayPanel::update() should run on a different thread.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: According to the official QT doc (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), what I am doing is essentially the same as their suggested method 2. And it says "all of QThread's queued slots and invoked methods will execute in the old thread", which is the behavior I want. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean main thread with '`DisplayPanel::update()` should run on a different thread.' ?

Comment: Yes, because that is the thread that instantiated the display panels

Comment: The more panels you create the more work is being done across the `paintEvent` member of those panels.  That being the case I'm not entirely surprised by some degradation on the worker thread -- those cpu cycles have to come from somewhere.  Can you edit your question to provide some measurements?

Comment: Make sure you test release build code for performance. I have seen cases where debug took 100 times longer than release to execute.

Comment: ***the increased number of signals-and-slots connections should not affect the performance of Worker very much because the queued requests to DisplayPanel::update() should run on a different thread*** The multithreaded queuing has a runtime cost due to needing to be atomic.

Comment: You need to use the profiler to find the bottleneck